# relation between splits and blocks in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to understand how mapreduce's InputFormat class is supposed to be working with respect to splits and blocks.

If I understand correctly:

- a hdfs file is split into blocks. Each block is guaranteed to be on a specific machine, but 2 blocks of the same file can be on 2 different machines.
- a split roughly defines an hdfs file and a starting byte offset + ending byte offset (or can it be a starting line number and ending line number?)
- each mapper will receive a split and an instance of a RecordReader with an instance of a specific split. Defining N splits mean that N mappers and RecordReaders are created, one for each split
- however a split size doesnt need to be divisible by the blocksize, or the other way around

Is that correct?

However, is the RecordReader instance mandated by the API to strictly process / work on the data inside its split ? or is it allowed to read data outside its split bounds ? Can it still always read any part of the file even if it has to go beyond the current block ? (so potentially the following of the file is on another machine)
In essence, are the splits only a "hint" for the recordreader?

Because if this is not the case and the splits are strict, it seems to me impossible to process a simple file where each record has non-fixed size.